# How to get type checkings with definition files while using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

I am trying to get types in Visual Studio Code when using plain JavaScript with CommonJS modules.

My full attempt is here: https://github.com/Guerric-P/test-typescript

Here are the relevant details:

**tsconfig.json**

```
"baseUrl": "src/typings",
"typeRoots": [
  "src/typings"
],
```

**src/index.js**

```
const { tuple } = require('./test-typescript');
```

**src/test-typescript.js**

```
const tuple = ['value1', 'value2'];

module.exports = {
  tuple
}
```

**src/typings/test-typescript.d.ts**

```
export const tuple: ['value1', 'value2'];
```

Result when I hover `tuple`: [image]

I expect the `['value1', 'value2']` type to appear instead of `string[]`.

I have tried many other things (`rootDirs`, dedicated folder with a `index.d.ts` file inside) but to no avail.

Comment: If you put `test-typescript.d.ts` in the same folder as `test-typescript.js`, VS Code should be able to recognise your manual type definitions. If you don't do the latter, how would inference disambiguate the exported `tuple` member if you had multiple JS files which did this? I don't think `typeRoots` is appropriate for what you're doing here because you're not consuming an external package.

Comment: So according to you I can't have JavaScript files and definition files in separate folders? I read in the docs that the folder structure of the `typeRoots` folder had to be the same as the JavaScript folder structure in order to disambiguate the potentially colliding exports.